# Render page callback output in another region than "content"

Tags: theming, routes

I am implementing `hook_menu` and I want to render the output of one `page callback` in a certain region, other than `content`.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a page via `hook_menu` it is better to define a block that you can place everywhere across the site.

Is there any requirement that restricts you to using a page?

If not the following code creates a block:

```
/**
* Implements hook_block_info().
*/
function YOUR_MODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();
  $blocks['YOUR_BLOCK_ABC'] = array(
    'info' => t('YOUR BLOCK NAME'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_view().
*/
function YOUR_MODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'YOUR_BLOCK_ABC':
      $block['subject'] = '';
      $block['content'] = _YOUR_MODULE_BLOCK_ABC_CONTENT();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}

function _YOUR_MODULE_BLOCK_ABC_CONTENT() {
  // This is where you code you use for the page goes.
  return t('Hello world');
}
```

Code from http://kahthong.com/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-drupal-block-programmatically

You can restrict the block visibility in the block settings to only be shown on single pages. Maybe this might solve the problem. To access arguments from the current page you can use the [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.

Cheers
j

Comment: Hey! Well.. I am not restricted to using `hook_menu`, but I wanted to create something directly on a certain page and I thought that was most straight way of doing it. So there is no way of forcing the output of the `page callback` to a certain region, eh?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know about something like that unless you digg into your theme and check for the path before rendering. Blocks are actually pretty straight forward, too I think ;)

Comment: without using a `hook_menu` there's no URL defined, so the block renders on a 404 page, only based on it's visibility settings. has anyone found a workaround for this other than @Marian

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to move the output from the `content` region to the `content_top` custom region like this:

```
function MYMODULE_page_alter(&$page)
{
    list($path) = explode('/', current_path());

    if ('shopping-list' == $path) {
        $page['content']['#region'] = 'content_top';
        $page['content_top'] = $page['content'];
        unset($page['content']);
    }
}
```